# Delete scdf old db data--spring-cloud-dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there a standard way to cleanup or remove old data from the database wrt job/task in scdf

I looked up the documentation. I could not find any information about it.

the last option would be manually create scripts/queries to remove data from individual tables like batch_job_execution etc.. But again since the tables are related need to get the

Answer (score 0):

In v2.2.x, we have added the ability to delete Task/Job executions from the history based on date range and other options.

You could either programmatically delete it using the [REST API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-executions-delete) or use the Dashboard selection from the Task Executions list page, to delete the historical executions in bulk.

It is available for both individual Tasks and Composed Tasks.